# How to convert alphabetical input to numbers and add them together

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm trying to convert user input into only alphabets, and convert each alphabet into a number(ex. a=1, b=2), then the numbers together. I've been able to complete the first part, but not sure how to do the second part.

```
import re
name = input("Name: ")
cleaned_name = filter(str.isalpha, name)
cleaned_name = "".join(cleaned_name)
print("Your 'cleaned up' name is: ", cleaned_name)
numbers = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10,'k':11,'l':12,'m':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,
       'q':17,'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,'u':21,'v':22,'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26}
for al in range(len(cleaned_name)):
    print(numbers,sep='+')

#if input is jay1joe2, cleaned name will be jayjoe
#after the 'numerology', will print the following below
#10+1+25+10+15+5 = 66
```

Comment: why import `re` if you're not using it?

Comment: read your favourite python tutorial again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for what you're trying to do.

> Note: I'm hardcoding the name here rather than using the user `input`, so it's easier to test it out if needed.

```py
import string

# name = input("Name: ")
name = 'jay1joe2'

cleaned_name = filter(str.isalpha, name)
cleaned_name = "".join(cleaned_name)
print("Your 'cleaned up' name is: ", cleaned_name)

numbers = {char: i for i, char in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, start=1)}

result = list(map(numbers.get, cleaned_name))
print(*result, sep='+', end=' ')
print('=', sum(result))
```

Where the second part (after `numbers`) could also be written alternatively as follows, using f-strings in 3.6+:

```py
result = [numbers[c] for c in cleaned_name]
print(f"{'+'.join(map(str, result))} = {sum(result)}")
```

Result:

```
Your 'cleaned up' name is:  jayjoe
10+1+25+10+15+5 = 66
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Name: ")
name = name.lower()
name1 = list(name)
Addition: int = 0
for k in name1:
    if ord(k)-96 < 1 or ord(k)-96 > 26:
        pass
    else:
        Addition = Addition + ord(k) - 96
print(Addition)
```

We can use ascii codes for Numbers and Characters :)